# Jquery / window.onbeforeload in custom jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add to this code a "`window.onbeforeload`" event to show a message that prevent the user from quitting the current page without adding the products to cart.

I have to show only when the quantity in > than 0 and with respecting the code below.

How can I do that ?

```
 <form>   <p><input class="qty"
 type="text" maxlength="1" value="0"  /></p>
<p><input class="qty" name="text"
type="text" value="0"  /></p> <p><input
 class="qty" name="text2" type="text"
/></p> </form>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(".qty").change(function(e) {
     if(this.value != '3' && this.value != '6' && this.value != '9') {
         this.value = 0;         
         alert('You can buy only 3, 6, or 9 pieces fromn this product');
     } }); </script>
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why everyone is suggesting globals. This method requires no globals and no `change()` listener (which you may still need if you want that alert there). Based on [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload), assuming support for `[].indexOf`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var e = e || window.event;

  if (['3','6','9'].indexOf($(".qty").val())>=0) {
    return;
  }
  else {
    var msg = 'You can buy only 3, 6, or 9 pieces from this product';

    // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
    if (e) {
      e.returnValue = msg;
    }
    // For Safari
    return msg;
  }

};
```

With multiple inputs you will need to change the condition slightly:

```
var valid = true;
$('.qty').each(function(){ valid = valid && ['3','6','9'].indexOf($(this).val())>=0; });

if (valid) {
   return;
}
else { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set some "global" variable. GLobal does not necessarily mean global to the window, just enough it's global in your own namespace (which you hopefully got).

```
if(this.value != '3' && this.value != '6' && this.value != '9') {
    NotifyTheUser = true;
}
else {
    NotifyTheUser = false;
}

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if( NotifyTheUser ) {
        return 'Check your input.. foo bar yay!';
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can save the value in some global variable and then `onbeforeunload` look for that value, whether it's greater than 0 or not.

```
var valueContainer = 0;
$(".qty").change(function(e) { 

valueContainer = this.value;
//rest of your code
});

window.onbeforeunload = function() {     
if( valueContainer == 0) {         
return 'Please Don't go away without selecting any product :(';    
 } };
```